# Relations between Linux distributions releases and updates

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can't explain the relations between updates for every release and the release itself.

Let's make an example.
Ubuntu has 14.04 LTS and 14.10.
Both of them are still supported, so what is the difference if I apply updates?
i.e., from https://packages.ubuntu.com I can clearly see that `weechat` package is updated to version 0.4 in 14.04, while it ships (or updates to) in 14.10.

The question is: what is the purpose of OS updates in every release and how the updates are entering (or not) in a release?

Comment: "what is the purpose of OS updates in every release" to keep things updated? "and how the updates are entering (or not) in a release?" following [their own release process?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseManagement#Release_Processes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the angle you're looking for.

My experience is Ubuntu but **release-based distributions**' releases *tend* to fix applications at a specific version. That is to say that if a new version of Gedit or OpenOffice comes out after release, that will not be pushed into the repositories.

Rather the older versions are maintained for a period of time set by the distribution. Game-breaking bugs and security issues are fixed during this time but it's very rare that feature updates are made.

There are exceptions to this. Firefox for example no longer maintains its own "stable" version. The latest version is the only thing Mozilla supports and backporting security fixes gets really complicated in a big application like that, so Ubuntu keeps their users at the latest release version of Firefox. Other things occasionally have security rationale. Ubuntu has a [Stable Release Updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) policy page for exceptions.

Conversely, **rolling-release distributions** can ship either the latest stable or latest dev, or some hybrid of the two. There is no rule across distributions.

Comment: Yes, you almost got it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to how, is “it depends”.

Linux is not one-thing. Most Gnu/Linux distros, are made of Gnu tools + Linux kernel + X11 windowing system + kde or gnome or unity or ? desktop + lots of applications. Each distro is different in the way that it is managed and updated.

There are all there own project. The project is managed the way that the people in the project want to manage it.